# Bash function argument unexpectedly interpreted as file/directory

Tags: linux, bash, function, dotfiles, unix-head

I created a function in my `.bashrc` file to print the top N files/directories in the working directory:

```
# .bashrc
function topN () { du -hs * | sort -rh | head -"$1"; }
```

However, sourcing my `.bashrc` and then running `topN 5` returns:

```
head: cannot open '5' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I have attempted various quoting methods and combinations, with generally the same error. How can I re-write this function to treat the argument `5` as a value rather than a file/directory?

Simply running `du -hs * | sort -rh | head -5` returns the expected listing of the top 5 files/directories and their sizes.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue.  If you call it as `topN 6` does the error message change?  Make sure you are using the current version of your function (declare -f topN).  Run `du -hs * > du.txt` and update question with said data (run your program in a sub-directory to ensure it only has information you care to have public).

Comment: Yup my bad, works on this side.

Comment: You would get this error if `$1` contained a space.   How are you calling the function?

Comment: Interestingly, naming the function `topN` works, but `topn` produces the error.

Comment: @IslandPatrol hmm... makes no difference here (either works).

Comment: do you  have an alias with the same name as `topn` ?

Comment: You would tell, perhaps, with `alias |grep -i topn`

Comment: Indeed, that was the issue. Apparently my shell had a stale alias with that name. Thanks for the help! Problem resolved.

Comment: Consider changing $1 to ${1:-5} or whatever you use most.  Makes these kinds of scripts easier to live with.

Comment: Good general tip. In this case, `head` returns a default of 10 entries, which is reasonable for my use case.

Comment: It does no find/show hidden files though, files/directories that starts with a `.`

Comment: Hidden files and directories can be accounted for by omitting the `*` and substituting `-a` in place of `-s`:
`du -ha | sort -rh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were running a (stale) alias rather than the function you shared with us.

Comment: Note that by adding an answer and having it upvoted or accepted, you blocked the OP from deleting their own question. For a question that's off-topic (in this case, eligible for close on acount of being "resolved in a way unlikely to help other users"), that's poor form.

Comment: Shall I un-accept the answer @CharlesDuffy?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hmm... root cause was: I thought that I was doing x but actually doing y.  This is debugging 101.  Makes no difference to me.  It usually annoys me when people delete their question after I answered it (only they derived value of my effort instead of the larger community).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you mentioned "you blocked the OP from deleting their own question". However, there is a [Delete question] link presented at the top of my screen. Unless this is a case of poor UI design, it appears that I could, in fact, delete the question.

Comment: @IslandPatrol, if you don't have enough reputation points it won't let you do that if the question is open and has an upvoted answer. (That's a deliberate design decision, because we've long had a problem with students asking questions to support their homework, then deleting them to hide evidence of academic dishonesty after receiving an answer). If it's being permitted for you right now, I suspect that's likely on account of the question being closed (or perhaps the threshold below which that rule applies is much lower than I remember).